# Folding files in the navigation bar in webstorm

Tags: coffeescript, webstorm

Iam using Webstorm for a project that uses coffeescript and Sass. In the navigation bar, I see coffeescript files along with the compiled js and map files. In the same way I see css files with the scss files. I want to be able to fold js and map files inside the corresponding coffee file for ease of navigation. I am not sure how to fix the settings for this. I want the  same for scss and css files.

Comment: You cannot do this manually (i.e. any files you want at any time). It's done automatically by File Watcher plugin. So .. if your *.coffee files are compiled in WebStorm by using File Watcher .. then it should be working/done automatically. If you have File Watcher already setup -- delete intermediate files (.js/.map) and force run that file watcher.

Comment: What if I am using an external filewatcher like grunt-contrib-watch?

Comment: It only works if those files were generated after running File Watcher. IDE checks for new files and compares them with file watcher settings ("output paths to refresh" field, I beleive) -- based on that it creates such folding. External file watcher is executed autonomous of IDE's File Watcher .. therefore such files will not be "grouped".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You cannot do this manually (i.e. any files you want at any time).**

It's done automatically by File Watcher plugin. So .. if your `*.coffee` files are compiled in WebStorm by using **File Watcher** .. then it should be working/done automatically.

If you have File Watcher already set up -- delete intermediate files (`.js/.map`) and force run that file watcher.

---

**Such grouping works if those extra files were generated after running File Watcher.** IDE checks for new files and compares them with file watcher settings (`Output paths to refresh` field, I believe) -- based on that it creates such folding.

External file watcher (i.e. `grunt-contrib-watch`) is executed autonomous of IDE's File Watcher .. therefore such files will not be "grouped".

---

**Related tickets** (those few that I'm aware of) that ask about additional settings to be able to create such nesting/grouping manually:

- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-8658
- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-7635
- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-113347

---

**UPDATE 2017/08/10:**

As of **2016.3.x** version such grouping/nesting is no longer relies on File Watchers -- it has special hard-coded rules for most common scenarios.

As of **2017.2** such rules are editable and available via Project View panel settings.

Answer (score 4):

Yes,you can!

After google for hours,I find the answer.

1. Select such file(s)/folder(s) in Project View panel
2. "Help | Find Action" (Ctrl + Shift + A), activate check box for better results
3. Search for "run file watchers" (without quotes, obviously) and choose Run File Watchers entry.

see more:

[PHPStorm - Run Filewatcher on existing files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20011138/phpstorm-run-filewatcher-on-existing-files/20012655#20012655)

Comment: I dont actually want to run file watchers. I want to be able to group files without having to run file watcher. Maybe we could create a rule, to do so.

Comment: I think this feature is supported by file watchers,may be you can write a file watcher yourself.Sorry I can't supply any help about this.