# Files not under caret on new computer

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I opened my project on another computer, and the files where I'd been using a file watcher were expanded, like before they used to be nested like `home.scss` is now after I run the watcher once on that file.

Is there a way to automatically make all the files be nested?

Because when adding new files and folder with git, it would be quite troublesome to go into each and every file in order to make them become nested.

Like I have some minified JavaScript files that used to be nested, but now is expanded for some reason.

Hope you understand. Thank you.

Edit: Nested***

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to automatically make all the files go under a caret like that?

Unfortunately not. Such nesting information (to *"go under a caret"* as you are saying) is taken from "Output path to refresh" field of the corresponding File Watcher.

You have to run file watcher for such files at least once in order to see files nested like you have it on your another computer.

Here is how **you can run File Watchers manually without the need to modify those files** (so no extra history will appear in your git (or whatever VCS you may be using there)).

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20012655/783119

---

**P.S.**

In PhpStorm **2016.3** (the next version that will be released in 1.5-2 months or so) such nesting will be done automatically (the most common combinations) so there will be no need to have File Watchers for providing such info.

If you wish -- you can try **EAP build** [right now](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2016/09/phpstorm-2016-3-eap-163-4396/) (EAP means Early Access Program .. which is sort of Alpha/Beta builds (simply speaking).. and therefore some bugs for new functionality might be present and performance may not be optimal).