# How to compile all scss files located in different folders?

Tags: ruby, compilation, sass, phpstorm

I have a file structure as follows:

```
all_skins
|— 1
  |— css
     |- _skinVariables.scss
     |— file.scss
     |— file.css
|— 2
  |— css
     |- _skinVariables.scss
     |— file.scss
     |— file.css
|— 3
  |— css
     |- _skinVariables.scss
     |— file.scss
     |— file.css
common_css
| _specificCode.scss
| _otherCode.scss
```

Inside my `scss` file for each "skin" I'm importing some general scss partials such as `_skinsVariables` and `_specificCode`. The _skinVariables partial changes for each skin, and the _specificCode is a general partial reused in all the scss files located outside the `all_skins` directory.

The problem is that whenever I make a change in the `specificCode` partial file, I need to recompile manually each scss file to generate the new css with the modified code.

I'm using PhpStorm's file watcher, so any change to the specific scss file triggers the watcher, but a modification to the included _specificCode (or any included partial) doesn't trigger it.

Is there any way to compile all the scss files inside a parent folder? There are over 30 of these numbered sub-folders, so doing it by hand is time consuming.

Any solution using command line, PhpStorm itself, or other software such as grunt will do for me (least desired).

**Edit:**

The file.scss would be as follows:

```
@import "skinVariables";
@import "../../../common_css/specificCode"
```

To be a bit clearer, the problem is that I have the partials included in all my file.scss, to make life easier most of the code comes from the partials.

When I modify a partial that is imported in all the files, such as _specificCode.scss, I would need all the file.scss to be re-compiled, but this doesn't happen.

The way the watchers seem to work at the moment is that they're triggered *only* when a modification is done to the file.scss itself, not to the partial that is being included.

Any work around this?

Comment: **1)** What are your File Watcher settings? **2)** is that `_specificCode` (or whatever) file that "does not work" is inside the project? **3)** I assume that you can compile your individual skins just fine (in other words: current file watcher works). **4)** And changes to `_skinsVariables` are processed normally (skin gets compiled)?

Comment: **1)** Here they are in phpstorm: https://gyazo.com/2cd504495766e57099d22063dcd1a75d **2)** Yeah, its part of the project but outside of the all_skins file. **3)** I can compile them manually just fine, they compline automatically *only* if I edit the file itself **4)** nope, changes to the included partials dont trigger the watcher

Comment: Lets make things clear for me - you have FileWatcher set - everything works fine - except when you make changes into _specificCode.scss? I do not understand to this "but a modification to the included _specificCode (or any included partial) doesn't trigger it." - by "any included partial" you mean what?

Comment: @HonzaRydrych not only to that specific file, but to any partial. Modifying a partial doesn't re-compile all the .scss files that have that partial included, even if they're being watched.

Comment: Can you please alter the filesystem structure, in your original question, with tags what is partial and where _specificCode.scss and _skinVariables.scss lives?

Comment: Done, I also added an edit to explain myself better and how the file.scss is importing the partials @HonzaRydrych

Comment: Well ... **1)** You are `Track only root files` option enabled -- that's good -- it meant to run file watcher for main file instead of included; You may wish to disable "Immediate file sync` option though; **2)** With Scope "Open Files" it may not work that well -- try "Project Files" for now. **3)** My main concern is -- this file gets included in many "root" files -- maybe this is what causing it? But it seems to work fine here with LESS (much simpler project though).

Comment: If those changes to File Watcher is not enough, you may try 1) answer by  Honza Rydrych 2) Manually trigger re-run of File Watchers -- see http://stackoverflow.com/a/20012655/783119

Comment: @LazyOne hah! I've been using your solution from that question so far, but I was getting tired of running 30+ file watchers manually every time. I solved the problem using a batch file that runs all of them, but it's not a nice, flexible solution. I'll try honza's answer though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So now you have the file watcher set to watch the open files and in case of modification it should compile ONLY the file itself.

What you need is to set your scss transpiler to compile the /all_skins/1/css/file.scss, /all_skins/2/css/file.scss, etc., but I don't know if the ruby transpiler you're using is capable of this setting.

I solved something similar with http://gulpjs.com (Grunt alternative) with Gulpfile.js config like this (altered to your paths):

```
gulp.task('styles', function() {
    return gulp.src([
            'all_skins/**/*.scss'
        ])
        .pipe($.sass())
        .pipe($.autoprefixer('last 3 version'));
});
```

Then set a PhpStorm's file watcher to watch whole `all_skins` and `common_css` folder (can be set by "scopes") and run gulp task named "styles" and it should work.

Comment: Yeah, I was heading towards that solution as well but using npm, it looks like the best option. Thanks Honza.