# PhpStorm file watcher does not watch for MJML files

Tags: phpstorm, file-watcher

I have installed the MJML from node package manager globally and then created a mjml filetype in PhpStorm and added a new File Watcher for MJML files with the following settings.

```
Name: MJML
Type: MJML from the dropdown
Program: /usr/bin/mjml
Argument: --watch $FileName$ -o $FileNameWithoutExtension$.html
Working Directory: $FileDir$
```

**PhpStorm Version**

```
PhpStorm 2016.3.2
Build #PS-163.10504.2, built on December 20, 2016
Licensed to PhpStorm Evaluator
Expiration date: April 3, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-408-b6 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
```

For some reasons it does not watch and generate the output file.

Comment: File Watcher gets executed on File Save event (manual or automatic) or file modification detection (e.g. file modified outside of IDE). 1) If you choose to "Show Console: Always" in that File Watcher settings -- will it be shown at all? 2) Will it run if you force re-run of File Watchers (http://stackoverflow.com/a/20012655/783119) 3) Does that file actually fits that user-created MJML File Type? 4) Some screenshots would be welcome

Comment: *(for reference purposes)* The same asked on PhpStorm Forums: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000117404-PhpStorm-file-watcher-does-not-watch-for-MJML-files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just checked - the watcher

[image]

does generate the output file. But you need to refresh the project manually using `File | Synchronize` to see the generated file, and watcher never completes.

This is the expected behavior: PhpStorm waits for exit code from a tool run as file watcher in order to refresh virtual file system. As MJML run with `--watch` option is kept running until you kill it, and thus doesn't return exit code when file generation completes,  VFS is not auto-synchronized, and the watcher is kept running. So, the solution is to use `-r` instead of `--watch`:

```
-r $FileName$ -o $FileNameWithoutExtension$.html
```

You have already registered mjml as a watcher in PHPStorm, no need to pass `--watch` to it

Comment: The above solution works in Mac but in Lubuntu, it does not. The problem is if I set the Mjml filetype in the File Watcher the file watcher is not starting. If I set Any it starts and generates the HTML file.