# Issue with WebStorm IDE not compiling one of my SCSS files

Tags: css, sass, webstorm

I'm using the JetBrains WebStorm IDE and I have a file watcher enabled so that all my SCSS files get compiled into CSS files.

This works on all my SCSS files EXCEPT the one named `Main.scss`.

Is `main` a special keyword or something? I literally copied and pasted the contents of `Main.scss` into a new SCSS file and the new one compiled immediately. It just seems really weird that the only SCSS file that won't compile is `Main.scss`.

Any ideas why?

Comment: no,  'main' is not a special keyword. Check you file watcher scope/file associations (make sure that 'Main.scss' is associated with SCSS file type and included in your file watcher scope)

Comment: If you force re-running of File Watcher on that file (as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/20012655/783119) -- will it compile that file now? Anything interesting in `idea.log` file (Help | Show Log in...)?