# PhpStorm SCSS trigger compilation on partial change

Tags: sass, phpstorm

First of all I have to note that this all worked well some time ago. I have returned to project after some time. Meanwhile I have updated PhpStorm and migrated to Win10. Everything else stayed untouched.

I have problem with triggering scss parial compilation. When I make changes in root file "global.scss" everything works ok - partials are also compiled. However when I make changes in partials PhpStorm not triggers compilation of root file.

PhpStorm version: 2017.2.3

File structure:

[image: file structure]

Watcher config:
[image: watcher config]

Scope config:

[image: scope config]

global.scss

[image: global.scss]

I have tried a lot - nothing works. It seems that partials - prefixed with underscore are just ignored by file watcher.

**EDIT:**
I found something - it seems that wildcard in scope pattern ignores underscored files. However partials are marked as included in files tree. I temporarly changed scope to project files and it works well - unfortunetally I can not leave this setting.

**EDIT2:**
I don't know is it bug or feature but PhpStorm handles nested Source roots in strange way. Check this file structure:

[image: file structure]

Without source root for scss directory, compilation is triggered even with scope pattern. However compiled css is placed in wrong directory - so it is not usable.

Comment: Please check the scope were the files will be watched. You have a scope called `init` selected. Check if the directory `scss` is included recursively.

Comment: @muecas yes it is

Comment: Sometimes in Win10 (on network mounts) i need to focus out of PHPStorm window in order to get the watchers executed. If you change a partial and select another program (or click on the desktop) does the watcher task gets executed?

Comment: I set trigger to manually execute on save (Ctrl + S)

Comment: **1)** Will force run of File Watcher do the job? Just to check if it works overall. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20012655/783119 **2)** Delete file watcher; Save settings; create it again -- try this, may help. Make backups first if so desired.

Comment: @LazyOne new informations included

Comment: Where do you place your compiled file? Why do you need that folder marked as "source"? Where did you read about it.

Comment: Your `*.scss` files are in `.../default/scss` folder .. and I guess output is in `.../default/css`. You do not need "Source" folder for that. And therefore you do not need to reference it in the file watcher (the `$SourcepathEntry$` variable and related) -- you should handle it all without it.

Comment: Yes it could work for global.scss, but I have also directory layouts/ were "main" scss files are also stored. That is why I had to use $FileDirRelativeToSourcepath$. As I mentioned before in older release of PhpStorm it was handled in different way.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not understand the issue you are having with `layouts` folder. Your structure is not complex so it should work for you. Get rid of "Source" and references to that in File Watcher and try to build it without them (the best way: disable this and make new file watcher) -- we should see how it can be resolved **P.S.** Please use `@username` otherwise there will be no "new message" notifications.

Comment: You can try parametrized macro `$FileDirPathFromParent(src)$`, it returns `foo/bar` for `some/path/src/foo/bar/baz.scss`

Comment: @LazyOne that is it! Awesome :) I could check macros myself. Thanks a lot for your time. Post answer so I can reward you with points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your info and investigation: you are using nested "Source" folder (on `scss`) and `$SourcepathEntry$` & related macro... which does not seem to work as you expected in your IDE version.

Get rid of it -- your setup does not need it at all. Your folder structure is pretty standard so it can be resolved using more "standard" ways.

- Disable this File Watcher for now (you may delete it later) and make new one.
- There try `$FileDirPathFromParent()$` parametrized macro (it accepts parameters). **For example** for `$FileDirPathFromParent(src)$` it returns `foo/bar` for `some/path/src/foo/bar/baz.scss` file path. This macro should do the job when making the needed path.