# How to use WebStorm FileWatcher for current file only

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, prettier-eslint

I want to create a custom WebStorm Filewatcher rule that performs `prettier-eslint` on save for the currently edited file. For my arguments, is there a way to declare that the command should be used for only the current edited file? You can see below for the file watcher rule I'm trying to create. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: *"...should be used for only the current edited file?"* Please note: the File Watcher can be triggered for the externally modified file (that option is enabled on your screenshot) as well or even manually (by triggering the [Run File Watchers actions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20012655/783119). Therefore the "currently edited file" has a very broad meaning here...

Comment: Anyway: **1)** just click on the `+` icon in the `Arguments` filed -- it will show all available macro (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/new-watcher-dialog.html#ws_file_watcher_dialog_tool_to_run_on_changes), e.g. `$FileName$`, `$FileNameWithoutExtension$` -- this will point to a specific (current) file. **2)** You can use `Current File` **Scope** -- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/using-file-watchers.html#ws_filewatcher_type_and_location_of_input_files

Comment: **P.S.** 1) Use absolute file path in the `Program` field. Internally (in the config file) the IDE will store such path relative to the project root. 2) You may want to disable "Auto-save edited file" option otherwise file watcher will be run automatically ~1sec after the last keypress, regardless if you finished working or just keep thinking on what to write next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The config below can be used to have the filewatcher watch only the current file.

[image]